# Execute function in React with Redux after the update of the STATE made by the dispatch of an action?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, axios, es6-promise, redux-thunk

I’m using **React** with **Redux** and **Thunk** *middleware*.

In my app I’m using **Axios** to interact with a Web Api that require Bearer Authentication. I’m using interceptor to intercept when the request status is *401 Not Authorized*. In this case I have an action that refresh the TOKEN and save it in my Redux Store.

In my Axios interceptor I want to re-execute my unauthorized request (with `axios.request(error.config)`) immediately after the execution of the Redux action that refresh and save a new token. I need to execute when I have the new TOKEN saved in my store.

How should be my action?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retry the request with the same config, and only change the authToken you could try something like this:

```
const authenticationProvider = (
  store,
  authAction
) => {
  axios.interceptors.response.use(
    response => response, 
    e => setResponseInterceptor(e)
  );
}


const setResponseInterceptor = (e, authAction, store) => {
  if (
    e.config &&
    e.response &&
    e.response.status === 401 &&
    authAction
  ) {
    console.log('401 intercepted', e);
    return store.dispatch(authAction()).then(_ => api.request(e.config));
  }

  return Promise.reject(e);
};
```

And on your App.js where you call the Redux Provider call the authProvider like this

```
authenticationProvider(reduxStore, () => { 
  /* Re authenticate function */
  // here you should call the auth service again and save the response on redux
  // or call the re-auth action with reduxStore.dispatch( /* ACTION */)
});
```

Thanks and happy coding!

Comment: Sorry @AxelBrei but I didn't understand your answer. What is authenticationProvider in your code? I'm able to intercept the response with code 401 and I'm able to run again the request. The problem is that the request should start after the update of the STATE made with my auth action.

Comment: @ChristianCascone the authenticationProvither is just the function name where you wrap all the logic to recall the backend and try to authenticate again. What i'm doing inside the interceptor its catching the request error, so it shouldn't dispatch the action after the request. 
ALso if you need to wait for the response, use a Promise or async/await to handle the async request. Hope it help!